# Python: merging two model to create new model with both categorical data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, encoding, keras

I did create my model using one-day CSV file. Now on the second day when new data arrives, I wanted to train my same model without losing previous model values. 
I have categorical data whose encoding values are stored into .npy file in training and i am loading same encoding files in testing. Every hour new categorical data arrives.
Now how to merge two models?

Training side:

*encoding*

```
y = data[:,-1].values
x = data.iloc [:,0:11].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_x_0 = LabelEncoder()
labelencoder_x_0.fit(x[:, 0])
x[:, 0] = labelencoder_x_0.transform(x[:, 0])
np.save('x0.npy', labelencoder_x_0.classes_)
```

*load_previous_model*

```
json_file = open(filename, 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model1 = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model1_name = 'model1.h5'
model1.load_weights(model1_name)
print("Loaded model1 from disk")
```

*creating a new model for new data*

```
seed =2016
np.random.seed (seed)
model2 = Sequential ()
model2.add (LSTM (  30 , activation = 'tanh', inner_activation = 'hard_sigmoid' ,return_sequences=True, input_shape =(len(cols), 1) ))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))
model2.add(LSTM(30))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))
model2.add (Dense (output_dim =1, activation = 'linear'))
model2.compile (loss ="mean_squared_error" , optimizer = "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model2_json = model2.to_json()
with open("model2.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model2_json)
model2.save_weights("model2.h5")
print(">>>> Model2 saved to model2.h5 in the disk")
```

Now i have two model {model1 and model2} how can i merge it?
I saw some answers but couldn't understand.

```
newModel = Model([model1.input,model2.input], mergedOut???)
newmodel.fit (x, y, batch_size =20, nb_epoch =15, shuffle = False)
```

And what about new categorical data? Can i merge or append both file categorical data into one file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think your main concern is not about neural network since it uses LSTM; thus, can take any value in any length. But you need to update (merge) `LabelEncoder` classes because you also want to encode new values without fitting all data again.

Only data `LabelEncoder` stored is classes_; thus, we can easily merge two `LabelEncoder` with manipulating classes_ attribute. Check the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing


le1 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le1.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
print(le1.transform(['paris']))
print(le1.classes_)

le2 = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le2.fit(["munich", "istanbul", "new york"])
print(le2.transform(['istanbul']))
print(le2.classes_)


def combine_label_encoder(le1, le2):
    le_new = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le_new.classes_ = np.hstack((le1.classes_, le2.classes_))
    return le_new


le_combined = combine_label_encoder(le1, le2)
combined_cities = ['munich', 'tokyo', 'istanbul', 'paris']
print(le_combined.transform(combined_cities))
print(le_combined.classes_)
```

Output:

```
[1]
['amsterdam' 'paris' 'tokyo']
[0]
['istanbul' 'munich' 'new york']
[4 6 1 6]
['amsterdam' 'paris' 'tokyo' 'istanbul' 'munich' 'new york']
```

Also check [sklearn doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: You did not get my question. Using the first day of data i trained my model. Let's say day-1 model is model1 and I am storing model1 to the file. Now on the second day when new data arrived, I want to load the first day of the model along with its categorical values and trained with the second day of data and save a new model with new categorical data. Now on third-day load that new model with new data train it and save it as again new model so on. 2 question: 1) How to merge two model?  2) How to merge categorical data on second day onwards?